# How can I stop MS Word inserting a short line when saving as .htm?

Tags: html, hyperlink, ms-word

Here's my problem:

1. I write a MS Word document (.docx) that contains a hyperlink followed by a blank line followed by another hyperlink.
2. I save the file as Webpage, filtered (.htm).
3. A .html page is created.
4. I open the .html page using a web browser.
5. At the start of the blank line (between the two lines of hyperlinks) there is a short line, as if an underline of an invisible character.
6. I examine the html of the page and find that the html for that line includes class=MsoHyperlink

It appears as if MS Word is adding a hyperlink on the blank line. How can I remove the hyperlink so that the line stays blank when saved as .htm?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why MS Word was adding an invisible hyperlink there. But I solved it by overwriting the invisible hyperlink character with another normal character from elsewhere, then deleting the new normal character.